Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available in adding MapBox to Kotlin Compose
I've encountered this error that there seems to be no value even though I've already included the secret access token from MapBox website.
maven {
    url = uri("https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven")
    // Do not change the username below. It should always be "mapbox" (not your username).
    credentials.username = "mapbox"
    // Use the secret token stored in gradle.properties as the password
    credentials.password = providers.gradleProperty("sk.ACCESS TOKEN CODE").get()
    authentication.create<BasicAuthentication>("basic")
}

Error:
Settings file 'D:\FIT5046\mapbox_test2\settings.gradle.kts' line: 20

Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.
What can I do? Added all needed codes in build.gradle.kts(project), build.gradle.kts(app), gradle.properties, strings.xml, androidmanifest.xml.
